# Ruby RSA from exponent and modulus strings

Tags: ruby, rsa

I have an RSA public key modulus and exponent string.

I want to create a `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` from these two strings.

Basically they come in as:

- **n** = 'long string'
- **e** = '4-character string'

How would I do this in Ruby?
The end goal is to get this to the [JWT](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) gem.

## Update

I'm currently in Ruby 2.3.1, so this works:

```
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
key.e = OpenSSL::BN.new(Base64.decode64(e), 2)
key.n = OpenSSL::BN.new(Base64.decode64(n), 2)
```

However, it won't work during an upgrade.

Comment: Your update would work perfectly in any case by using `Base64.urlsafe_decode64` instead of `Base64.decode64` for old ruby version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working this way, based on this python implementation:

https://github.com/jpf/okta-jwks-to-pem/blob/master/jwks_to_pem.py

```
    key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
    exponent = kid_header['e']
    modulus = kid_header['n']


    # Voila !
    key.set_key(base64_to_long(modulus), base64_to_long(exponent), nil)

    def base64_to_long(data)
      decoded_with_padding = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(data) + Base64.decode64('==')
      decoded_with_padding.to_s.unpack('C*').map do |byte|
        to_hex(byte)
      end.join.to_i(16)
    end

    def to_hex(int)
      int < 16 ? '0' + int.to_s(16) : int.to_s(16)
    end
```

Comment: That's perfect!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JSON::JWT` gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/json-jwt, https://github.com/nov/json-jwt)

```
# can be found somewhere in `.well-known` space on the server
key_hash = {
  "kty": "RSA",
  "use": "sig",
  "kid": ...,
  "e": ...,
  "n": ...,
  "alg": "RS256"
}
jwk = JSON::JWK.new(key_hash)
JSON::JWT.decode token, jwk.to_key
# voila!
```

The same can be achieved with Ruby JWT (https://rubygems.org/gems/jwt, https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/blob/master/lib/jwt/jwk/rsa.rb)

```
public_key = JWT::JWK::RSA.import(key_hash).public_key
JWT.decode token, public_key, true, { algorithm: key_hash[:alg] }
```

Comment: In case someone struggle like me...
JWK support was added on jwt-ruby only on version 2.2.1
Beware of the version you are using in your project (I was using 1.5)

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby 2.4+ you should use :

```
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
key.set_key(n, e, d)
```

if you do not have `d` you can set it to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer did not work for me in OpenSSL v3. Check out this thread for a solution that works in OpenSSL v3.

[Creating RSA key with OpenSSL v3 using "modulus" and "exponent" doesn't work in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77209118/creating-rsa-with-opensslpkeyrsa-key-using-modulus-and-exponent-doesnt/77216212#77216212)

### Solution:

I found the first Gist that worked ***before*** OpenSSL v3, however it **did not work in the OpenSSL v3**. Thankfully, this great dude shared how to achieve this in OpenSSL v3 in the comments. Check out the second link for the Gist or the code below for the solution.

- ❌ Works in versions of OpenSSL before v3: https://gist.github.com/jooeycheng/0d5fbd039b6ec586c450b7486be5e049
- ✅ Works in OpenSSL v3: https://gist.github.com/WilliamNHarvey/0e37f84a86e66f9acb7ac8c68b0f996b

Sharing the Gist code here provided in the second link (just in case):

```rb
# Given n and e in typical encoding, like that found on a jwks well-known.
# For example for google, from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
n = "t0VFy4n4MGtbMWJKk5qfCY2WGBja2WSWQ2zsLziSx9p1QE0QgXtr1x85PnQYaYrAvOBiXm2mrxWnZ42MxaUUu9xyykTDxsNWHK--ufchdaqJwfqd5Ecu-tHvFkMIs2g39pmG8QfXJHKMqczKrvcHHJrpTqZuos1uhYM9gxOLVP8wTAUPNqa1caiLbsszUC7yaMO3LY1WLQST79Z8u5xttKXShXFv1CCNs8-7vQ1IB5DWQSR2um1KV4t42d31Un4-8cNiURx9HmJNJzOXbTG-vDeD6sapFf5OGDsCLO4YvzzkzTsYBIQy_p88qNX0a6AeU13enxhbasSc-ApPqlxBdQ"
e = "AQAB"

rsa = create_rsa_key(n, e)

def create_rsa_key(n, e)
  data_sequence = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence([
                                            OpenSSL::ASN1::Integer(base64_to_long(n)),
                                            OpenSSL::ASN1::Integer(base64_to_long(e))
                                          ])
  asn1 = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence(data_sequence)
  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(asn1.to_der)
end

def base64_to_long(data)
  decoded_with_padding = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(data) + Base64.decode64("==")
  decoded_with_padding.to_s.unpack("C*").map do |byte|
    byte_to_hex(byte)
  end.join.to_i(16)
end

def byte_to_hex(int)
  int < 16 ? "0" + int.to_s(16) : int.to_s(16)
end
```

Hope this helped!