# Creating RSA key with OpenSSL v3 using "modulus" and "exponent" doesn't work in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I have an RSA public key modulus and exponent string.
I want to create a OpenSSL::PKey::RSA using them in Ruby on Rails. I tried it three different ways and I think something is messed up about my environement, however, I can't spot it. Do you have any idea?

Versions:

```
ruby 3.2.1 (2023-02-08 revision 31819e82c8) [arm64-darwin22]
Rails 7.0.8
OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023
```

#### First Try

I do this:

```py
modulus = k['n']
exponent= k['e']
rsa = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
rsa.set_key_rsa(k['n'], k['e'], 2)
```

and I get error:

```
undefined method `set_key_rsa' for #<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x000000010a1468a0 oid=rsaEncryption>
```

#### Second try

I do this:

```rb
modulus = k['n']
exponent= k['e']
rsa = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
rsa.set_key(k['n'], k['e'], 2) # <---- used set_key
```

I get error:

```
rsa#set_key= is incompatible with OpenSSL 3.0
```

#### Third

```rb
rsa = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new
rsa.n = OpenSSL::BN.new(Base64.urlsafe_decode64(k['n']), 2)
rsa.e = OpenSSL::BN.new(Base64.urlsafe_decode64(k['e']), 2)
```

I get error:

```
undefined method `n=' for #<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x000000010ab56e08 oid=rsaEncryption>
```

Ugh, what's happening?

Comment: Not an answer, but [the PKEY structure became immutable in v3](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/blob/6b3dd6a372c5eabc88bf35a312937ee3e1a6a105/History.md#version-300) hence the `set_key` error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. - I am assuming you don’t know whether how people are doing it in Ruby post-openssl-v3-release  or if there is any alternative to openssl library that I can do this, do you?

Comment: first and third methods fail b/c you are calling methods that don't exist (#set_key_rsa, #n and #e respectively). Not sure why you thought these methods would work... they're not mentioned in the docs. The second method should work, it works for me. The error suggests you used `rsa.set_key =`, even though that's not what you show. OpenSSL is the right library. It has good documentation.

Comment: Sorry @dugong, it'd be something like what's shown [in the `generate_parameters` docs](https://ruby.github.io/openssl/OpenSSL/PKey.html#method-c-generate_parameters), but I'm not sure what the RSA names for the `n` and `e` are.

Comment: Hey @LesNightingill, thanks for trying to help. I have seen places that those methods are used. For example: https://gist.github.com/jooeycheng/0d5fbd039b6ec586c450b7486be5e049

Thank you @smathy. `n` and `e` are modulus and exponent of an RSA key provided in a keyset to create the secret of a JWT to decode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jump to solution part if you are not interested in what I was trying.

### Context:

I am creating an [LTI](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20LTI&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) tool that has a URL to get a keyset for verifying a JWT token sent from an LTI platform. Keys in the keyset has a modulus (`n`) and an exponent (`e`) value to create the RSA key that will decode the JWT.

There were two problems,

- in OpenSSL v3 `n` and `e` methods are not working anymore.
- it is not clear how to format modulus (`n`) and exponent (`e`) values properly to use the in certain methods

### Solution:

I found the first Gist that worked ***before*** OpenSSL v3, however it **did not work in the OpenSSL v3**. Thankfully, this great dude shared how to achieve this in OpenSSL v3 in the comments. Check out the second link for the Gist or the code below for the solution.

- ❌ Works in versions of OpenSSL before v3: https://gist.github.com/jooeycheng/0d5fbd039b6ec586c450b7486be5e049
- ✅ Works in OpenSSL v3: https://gist.github.com/WilliamNHarvey/0e37f84a86e66f9acb7ac8c68b0f996b

Sharing the Gist code here provided in the second link (just in case):

```rb
# Given n and e in typical encoding, like that found on a jwks well-known.
# For example for google, from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
n = "t0VFy4n4MGtbMWJKk5qfCY2WGBja2WSWQ2zsLziSx9p1QE0QgXtr1x85PnQYaYrAvOBiXm2mrxWnZ42MxaUUu9xyykTDxsNWHK--ufchdaqJwfqd5Ecu-tHvFkMIs2g39pmG8QfXJHKMqczKrvcHHJrpTqZuos1uhYM9gxOLVP8wTAUPNqa1caiLbsszUC7yaMO3LY1WLQST79Z8u5xttKXShXFv1CCNs8-7vQ1IB5DWQSR2um1KV4t42d31Un4-8cNiURx9HmJNJzOXbTG-vDeD6sapFf5OGDsCLO4YvzzkzTsYBIQy_p88qNX0a6AeU13enxhbasSc-ApPqlxBdQ"
e = "AQAB"

rsa = create_rsa_key(n, e)

def create_rsa_key(n, e)
  data_sequence = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence([
                                            OpenSSL::ASN1::Integer(base64_to_long(n)),
                                            OpenSSL::ASN1::Integer(base64_to_long(e))
                                          ])
  asn1 = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence(data_sequence)
  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(asn1.to_der)
end

def base64_to_long(data)
  decoded_with_padding = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(data) + Base64.decode64("==")
  decoded_with_padding.to_s.unpack("C*").map do |byte|
    byte_to_hex(byte)
  end.join.to_i(16)
end

def byte_to_hex(int)
  int < 16 ? "0" + int.to_s(16) : int.to_s(16)
end
```

Hope this helped!